# Prove that is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the set $V$ of square $3x3$ matrices that sattisfy these two conditions:

1) the sum of the first row and the third row is the vector $(0, 0, 0)^T$,
2) the sum of the elements on the main diagonal is $0$.

I should prove the set is subspace of $R^{3x3}$ and then find some five-element set of generators of this subspace.

To prove this set is a  subspace, I need to show the set is non empty, is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, that I can do. What I am not clear about is the second part. How do I find the set of generators here? And what is the purpose of the two conditions here?

Thank you.

Comment: How does a general element of V look like? Can you imagine? If not I give you an example :) (having a general form in mind your exercise becomes very easy)

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you have proved that it is a subspace. To find a system of generator of such subspace you may proceed as foloows:

1. Take any matrix in $V$, let us say  $$ \begin{pmatrix}  a &b & c  \\ d& e&f  \\  g& h& i \end{pmatrix}$$
2. What we have as a given: sum first and last row is the zero vector then  $ g=-a$ and  $ h=-b$ and $ i=-c$, so our arbitrary matrix can be written as $$ \begin{pmatrix}  a &b & c  \\ d& e&f  \\  -a & -b & -c  \end{pmatrix}$$
3. We have also that the sum of the diagola is  zero, $ a+e-c=0$,  so  $c=a+e $ thus your matrix can be written as
   $$ \begin{pmatrix}  a &b & a+e  \\ d& e&f  \\  -a & -b & -a-e  \end{pmatrix}$$
   Hence you arbitrary matrix can be written as
   $$ \begin{pmatrix}  a & b & a+e  \\ d& e&f  \\  -a & -b & -a-e  \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 1  \\ 0& 0&0  \\  -1 & 0 & -1  \end{pmatrix} +b\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0& 0&0  \\  0 & -1 &0 \end{pmatrix}   +e \cdots$$
   Continue, you will find the five desired  elements that generate the subspace  $V$.

Comment: Thanks, I almost had it, I just didnt think of wrtiting $c$ as $a+e$ so I always had six of them..:) 
To prove the set is a subspace, is it enought to show what I have written above or do I need to prove some other axioms?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \colon= [a_{ij}]_{3 \times 3}$ be an element of $V$. Then we must have 
$$a_{31} = -a_{11}, \ a_{32}=-a_{12}, \ a_{33} = -a_{13}, $$
and also 
$$a_{11} + a_{22}+ a_{33} = 0.$$
The last condition then becomes
$$a_{11}+ a_{22} -a_{13} = 0.$$
Or, 
$$a_{22} = a_{13} - a_{11}.$$
Thus, we can choose $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$, $a_{21}$, and $a_{23}$ independently, and the rest of the $a_{ij}$ are given by the formulas
$$a_{31} = -a_{11}, \ a_{32}=-a_{12}, \ a_{33} = -a_{13} \ \mbox{ and } \ a_{22} = a_{13} - a_{11}.$$

Therefore, the basis elements (or, what you call, generators) of this subspace can be found by taking one of the entries $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$, $a_{21}$, and $a_{23}$ to be $1$ turn by turn, while leaving all the others to be $0$, and of course using the above formulas to find the remaining entries of the matrix.

Hope you can continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a subspace $S$ of some vector space $V$ can be seen as a part of that space $V$ satisfying certain conditions.

You've got 2 conditions and are able to show it is a subspace, which is good.
Now the question 2 asks you to translate those conditions in "matrix" speech, by finding 5 generators. Well, here is a way to find them, but logical thinking and matrix play. I wouldn't call the following a "proof" or whatsoever, but it's kind of an "example" how to empirically do it.

How do you express that the sum of the first row and the third row is the vector $(0,0,0)^T$ ? Well you may use the following system :
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\end{pmatrix} \cdot M= \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now we apply this condition to the 9 base matrices of your space $V$ and we may get :
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  $$
We have 6 basis matrices for this subspace.

Now for your second condition, you may translate it as : "the trace of your matrix must be 0", but the trace is such that $Tr(A+B)= Tr(A)+Tr(B)$ and $Tr(\alpha A)=\alpha Tr(A)$, so amongst our basis matrices, only 3 of them are changing the value of the trace :
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
 So we need to "correct them", by linear combinations so that they won't interfer anymore, this means every time we are adding $\alpha  \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, we need to substracte $\alpha \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, hence we replace this matrix by :
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
The same holds for the second one  and we get :
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally we see that each times we have $$\alpha\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$, we need to add or substract either the first or the second of our 3 matrices in order to "correct" the trace to 0.
But this ends up in a matrix lineary dependent of either $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, so we can suppress this matrix from our basis. We end up with the generators :
 $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$

PS : please note that this is at most "messy" : it isn't formal enough ; but I would justify it as "you've just to find 5 generators, no matter how you do".
PPS : note that you may as well find 5 completely different generators using the same kind of process. Those would still generate the same space, and yours would then be "linear combinations" of mine, and vice-versa. (That would just be a "change of basis" while staying in the same subspace.)